# How I can find line(s) which the third columns is not digit/date?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, awk

I am trying to use awk command to find line(s) which the third columns is not digit/date? Suppose there is a file comma "," field separated, has three columns and as code "," measure "," dd/mm/yyyy,

```
97xx574,26.7,12/30/1997,
97xy575,18,12/30/1997,
code,meas,EXAMDATE,
B529ui,28.2,12/30/1997,
B530sx,26.4,12/30/1997,
J487sxv,21.5,12/30/1997,
```

I tried:

```
awk -F "," '/$3[^0-9].*/ {print $0}' <filename>
```

... but apparently it is not correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this.  Where 3rd field does not consist of 0-9 or /, print the line (which is the default action : no need for a `print $0`.

```
$3 = third field
!~ = where does not (!) match regular expression
/  = mark start of regular expression
^  = match start of field
[0-9/]+ = match any of the 0123456789/ characters at least once
$  = match end of field
/  = mark end of regular expression
```

So code, with output:

```
awk -F, '$3!~/^[0-9/]+$/' filename
code,meas,EXAMDATE,
```

Introducing a bit more checking, so has to consist of nn/nn/nnnn, try this.

```
awk -F, '$3!~/^[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' filename
code,meas,EXAMDATE,
```

Could even use `grep` if you wanted.

```
grep -vE '^.*,.*,[0-9/]+,$' x1
code,meas,EXAMDATE,
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if pre-October months are written with only one digit (or if the first nine days of a month are written with one digit).  Still, it's good.